# TeamCity won't publish project using MsDeploy

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy, webdeploy, msbuild-4.0

I have msbuild command to publish my project (WCF Service Application) that looks as follow:

```
msbuild FooBar.Service.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true;
DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish;
MSDeployServiceUrl=http://server.pl/MSDeployAgentService;
DeployIisAppPath="Foobar";
MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent;
UserName=Joe;
password=secret;
```

and this works from VS Command Prompt, all is published without any errors. Please note, that I'm not specyfing any Target.

But I want to create my Deployment Project using TeamCity (7.1.5). I have done simple project, and Configuration with one Build Step:

[image]

The problem is that, when I'm running this Task, msbuild compiles my site but **without publishing** it to remote server. Below is the build log:

```
[16:13:16]Checking for changes
[16:13:18]Publishing internal artifacts
[16:13:18][Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.start.properties.gz file
[16:13:18]Clearing temporary directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[16:13:18]Checkout directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\2eecf7b45f277a61
[16:13:18]Repository sources transferred
[16:13:18]Updating sources: server side checkout
[16:13:18]Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MsBuildBootstrap.exe /workdir:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\2eecf7b45f277a61 /msbuildPath:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
[16:13:18]in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\2eecf7b45f277a61
[16:13:20]Foobar.csproj.teamcity: Build target: Build
[16:13:20][Foobar.csproj.teamcity] CoreCompile
[16:13:20][CoreCompile] Csc
[16:13:20][Csc] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Configuration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Web.Entity.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Web.Services.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\Foobar.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output Service1.svc.cs IService1.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
[16:13:20][Foobar.csproj.teamcity] CopyFilesToOutputDirectory
[16:13:20][CopyFilesToOutputDirectory] Copy
[16:13:20][Copy] Copying file from "obj\Debug\Foobar.dll" to "bin\Foobar.dll".
[16:13:20][CopyFilesToOutputDirectory] Foobar.csproj -> C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\2eecf7b45f277a61\bin\Foobar.dll
[16:13:20][CopyFilesToOutputDirectory] Copy
[16:13:20][Copy] Copying file from "obj\Debug\Foobar.pdb" to "bin\Foobar.pdb".
[16:13:19]Targets was not defined in the build configuration.
[16:13:19]MSBuild command line parameters contain "/property:" or "/p:". It is recommended to define System Property on Build Parameters instead.
[16:13:21]Process exited with code 0
[16:13:21]Publishing internal artifacts
[16:13:21][Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
[16:13:21]Publishing artifacts
[16:13:21][Publishing artifacts] Collecting files to publish: [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\2eecf7b45f277a61]
[16:13:21][Publishing artifacts] Sending
[16:13:21]Build finished
```

Comment: Did you ever find out what the problem was?  I'm having the same difficulty.

Comment: Sorry @JeremyHolovacs, cant remember now, this is too old.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked through this in depth but noticed that in your command-line example you're specifying `DeployIisAppPath`, but looks like you're using `DeployAppPath` in your TeamCity script, which will just be ignored by MSBuild, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue for visual studio 2013 projects. another configuration just building and deploying fine

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noticing that you're getting the following warning:

```
MSBuild command line parameters contain "/property:" or "/p:".
It is recommended to define System Property on Build Parameters instead.
```

What it's saying is that the best practice for passing numerous parameters to command-line based executions is to define parameters as System Properties rather than explicitly concatenate them in one long string.

As a suggestion for refactoring, I'd recommend you to define the parameters that you're passing through /p: prefix as System Properties (this can be done on Build Parameters section of your Build Configuration). In this case they will be passed to executions behind the scenes and will help you to avoid duplication, get easily maintainable and so on. It will also make the parameters list more clear and help you to find out if there is something wrong with the parameters you're passing to MSBuild that may cause the issue.